# A monotone and bounded sequence $\{a_n\}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading a proof of a theorem.

**Theorem**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lemma_1

**Proof**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Proof

I do not understand how we end up with: $\left|c-a_{n}\right| \leq\left|c-a_{N}\right|<\varepsilon$. From this $a_N > c - \epsilon \implies c-a_N < \epsilon$ must $\left|c-a_{n}\right| \leq\left|c-a_{N}\right|<\varepsilon$ follow. But I can't see how.?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n \geq N$, so $a_n \geq a_N$ by the assumption that the sequence is increasing. $c$ is an upper bound for the sequence $\{a_j\}$, then $a_N \leq a_n \leq c$. Thus $a_N - c \leq a_n - c\leq 0$, hence $c-a_N \geq c-a_n \geq 0$, since multiplication by $-1$ inverts the inequality. Then $|c-a_N| = c-a_N$ and $|c-a_n| = c-a_n$, since they are both $\geq 0$. Thus $|c-a_N| \geq |c-a_n|$.

Comment: I do not think I was clear enough about my problem. So the problem is I can't see how $a_{N} \leq a_{n} \leq c$ implies $\left|c-a_{n}\right| \leq\left|c-a_{N}\right|$? By the way, is $a_N$ variable?

Comment: I'll add an edit to explain that. What do you mean by "is $a_N$ variable"? Once you fix some $N$, as you do in the proof, it is fixed.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. Thanks.

Comment: @Xenusi edit added.

Comment: Thanks. I have been sitting for 10 hours reading and solving problems so of course I forgot $\geq 0$ . Thanks! I appreciate.